# SELECTING Only Part of nvarchar SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm transferring data from one database to another (upgrading a system) and have a quick question.

In the source database (the one currently in use), I have a column that stores urls using absolute paths. In my new database, I am using relative paths. How can I trim out the absolute portion of the paths on the transfer (I'm using INSERT INTO), leaving only the file name?

Thanks!
Jack

Comment: Can you give some examples of the data in question?

Comment: Source column: 'http://www.example.com/audiofiles/myaudio.mp3'

Destination column: 'myaudio.mp3'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Val VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '\\test\tada.xml'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'tada1.xml'

SELECT  Val,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('\',Val,0) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Val,LEN(Val) - (CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(Val),0) - 1) + 1, CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(Val),0)) ELSE Val END
FROM    @Table
```

Alternatively you could create a CLR scalar function in C# that should make this a bit easier for you.

Have a look at [How to: Create and Run a CLR SQL Server User-Defined Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same amount of characters in the absolute path for every file you can just use SUBSTRING.  This is not the most maintainable solution, but for a one time query you should be ok.

Example.

```
DECLARE @filename varchar(50)
SET @filename = 'example.com/audiofiles/myaudio.mp3'

INSERT INTO newtable
(file_name)
VALUES
(SUBSTRING(@filename, 24, LEN(@filename) - 23))
```

Comment: +1. thanks. I'd mark as answer, but @astander was more repeatable.